# Refreshing config file values

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I have this strange problem having hard time correcting it. Whenever I update options in my config files it wont detect the changes. I will keep getting exception error saying that option not detected, even i refresh the VS-2012, re start VS02012 and IIS, refesh browsers. It takes long time before it will detect the changes and I can use them. Error I get is

```
System.Exception: unable to vend object, interface [abc.IExec] reference     [option.changeEmployees] ---> System.Exception: option set not found [api_changeEmployees]
```

While this config file has those options values is saved and updated. What is the fix? Help! Thanks.

Comment: Please show the relevant code.

Comment: Are you saving the changes that you make right away?  IIS *should* detect the changes and restart the process.

Comment: Also, if you are stepping through with the debugger and expecting changes to happen, I doubt it will work, since the application would have to restart to see the changes.

Answer (score 1):

Use configuration files for semi-static values, like connection strings, tcp/ip ports. For other settings that should be changed on the fly, use, for example, a ConfigurationTable.

Answer (score 0):

The process actually has to stop and restart to read in new config values.  The config values are read in the first time they're accessed and cached in a dictionary for the lifetime of the application.

[According to Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178685.aspx#calculating_configuration_settings_at_runtime) though, changing the config file and saving should trigger restarting the application.

If that doesn't work you should be able to just stop and start the app pool hosting your site or issue an IIS reset.